# PyTorchで行列計算

Tags: python, numpy, 深層学習, pytorch

PyTorchを使って、深層学習をしています。
forward計算内でnumpyのnp.tileやnp.reshapeなどを使っているのですが、Tensor型をnumpyのndarray型に変換してしまうと、requires_gradの情報が失われ、学習ができません。

Tensor型のままtileのような処理を実行する方法はありますでしょうか。

もしくは、requires_gradの情報を保持したまま、numpyで計算を行うことはできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

このような感じでいかがでしょうか。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import torch

# tile
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=torch.float32)
x.requires_grad_()
print(x)
x = x.repeat(2, 3)
print(x)

# reshape
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], dtype=torch.float32)
x.requires_grad_()
print(x)
x = x.view(2, -1)
print(x)
```

出力結果は以下の通りです。

```
luna:~ % ./testu1.py
tensor([[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]], requires_grad=True)
tensor([[1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2.],
        [3., 4., 3., 4., 3., 4.],
        [1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2.],
        [3., 4., 3., 4., 3., 4.]], grad_fn=<RepeatBackward>)
tensor([[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.],
        [5., 6.]], requires_grad=True)
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [4., 5., 6.]], grad_fn=<ViewBackward>)
```